# Flask-Login unregistered User gives 500 error

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am trying to make a simple Flask-login server following the code example on github. It works perfectly for a user that is in the program but if an incorrect username is input it gives a 500 Internal server error. Any suggestions would be awesome :)

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return '''
               <form action='login' method='POST'>
                <input type='text' name='email' id='username' placeholder='email'/>
                <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='password'/>
                <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
               </form>
               '''
               #return render_template('logins.html')
    # if request.method == 'POST':
        # username = request.form['username']
        # password = request.form['password']

    email = flask.request.form['email']
    if flask.request.form['password'] == users[email]['password']:
        user = User()
        user.id = email
        flask_login.login_user(user)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('protected'))
    return 'Bad login'



    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "serv.py", line 65, in login
    if flask.request.form['password'] == users[email]['password']:
KeyError: 's'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be good to see the error traceback from the Flask log. Also it is better to provide here the relevant code instead of a link for many reasons (the code in external source can be changed over time for example).

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question to add error traceback and your code for completeness.

I can have a rough speculation based on the behavior you are mentioning. You should have user_loader callback function, which you use to get the user before using `login_user(user)`. Based on your implementation, this function might be loading the user from a database or from in memory dictionary or list

It is very likely that you don't have exception handling in case the user doesn't exist for an instance if you are loading from dictionary, your code should look like below.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    try:
        user = users[userid]
        return user
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

The above code handles the exception and returns `None` in case the user does not exist. That why `flask-login` will be able to decide NOT to log your user in, whilst your program does not return an error.